# One-liner capturing output for sudo kill

Tags: linux, command-line, sudo, kill

**Background**

I have some root processes that I'm trying to kill, more precisely some `tcpdump` processes. 
Hence, I need to use `sudo kill`.

My current command looks something like this:

```
sudo kill $(ps aux | grep '[t]cpdump' | awk '{print $2}'
```

**Question**

Any ideas for extending the command (keeping it a one-liner) for having an output like below, redirected into a log file?

- In case of success:

  > Success! Killed processes: pid1 pid2 ...
- In case of failure:

  > Error! Some error message.

A simple redirect is not enough, as the kill command does not output the processes it killed.

Comment: There's also pkill, not sure about logging though, could use pgrep instead of your ps | grep | awk

Comment: Indeed, the command can be simplified with pkill, but I am interested in capturing the output/result.

Answer (score 3):

If killall's not working for you, and you need to match the full command line there's always `pgrep -f` + bash + logging, (even *technically* kept on one line...)

First a few lines

```
if tempkill1=$(pgrep -f "your_pattern")
then
  if kill $tempkill1 
  then
    echo Success killed $tempkill1 | tee -a logfile 
  else
    echo Error could not kill $tempkill1 | tee -a logfile
  fi
else
 echo No processes found | tee -a logfile
fi
```

or instead of if's

```
tempkill1=$(pgrep -f "your_pattern") && { kill $tempkill1 && echo Success \
killed $tempkill1 | tee -a logfile || echo Error could not kill \
$tempkill1 | tee -a logfile; } || echo No processes found | tee -a logfile
```

Or instead of all the tee's, redirect all stdout:

```
exec > >(tee -a logfile); tempkill1=$(pgrep -f "your_pattern") && { kill $tempkill1 \
&& echo Success killed $tempkill1 || echo Error could not kill $tempkill1; } || \
echo No processes found; exec > /dev/tty
```

---

Of course, without the logging, you only basically need `pkill -f`, or very minor logging of success/fail like:

```
pkill -f "your_pattern" && echo Success|tee -a log || echo Error|tee -a log
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `killall`.

```
killall -v tcpdump
```

If you want more diagnostics, check the return code of `killall`.

Comment: I am actually grep-ing for a specific tcpdump output file and killing the corresponding process. I am not looking to kill all tcpdump processes.
Something like: grep '[t]cpdump_someLabel.pcap'

Comment: killall has a `-r, --regexp` option, does it not work? @IllyesIstvan

Comment: @Xen2050
-r will interpret NAME as an extended regular expression. I am filtering based on output file, not the process name.

Comment: @IllyesIstvan I thought so, that's why I answered based around pgrep's full command line matching